# Is it possible to create a query that takes all distinct text from a column and creates new columns with that text?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

What I have is a column of users (Users) that shows everyone who completes a transaction. I am trying to pivot it to where each user has their own column that filters their data. I have managed to get it to work, but its currently hard coded in

```
select 
    column8 as 'Charges',
    sum(case when column9 = 'Bob' then column6 else 0 end) as Bon,
    sum(case when column9 = 'Susan' then column6 else 0 end) as Susan,
    sum(case when column9 = 'Eli' then column6 else 0 end) as Eli,
    sum(column6) as 'Total Charges'
```

What I would like to do is to make it so that my statement recognizes if there is a distinct name and then takes that name and makes it its own column. That way every name isn't hard coded in, and it will adjust to when names are added or removed.

Comment: All things are possible. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can use PREPARED Statement. This Query will work for you.

```
select CONCAT( 'SELECT column8 as \'Charges\', ', 
  GROUP_CONCAT('SUM(IF( column9 =\'', column9,'\', column6,0)) AS \'', column9,'\''
  SEPARATOR ','),
 ', sum(column6) as \'Total\' FROM mytable;') into @myquery 
from ( 
  SELECT column9 from mytable 
  GROUP BY column9 
  order by column9) as dis;
PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Sample**

*myTable*

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select * from mytable;
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | column6 | column8 | column9 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  0 |       1 |       7 | bob     |
|  2 |       1 |       2 | bob     |
|  3 |       1 |      99 | Susam   |
|  4 |       1 |       2 | Susam   |
|  5 |       1 |       6 | Susam   |
|  6 |       3 |       1 | Eli     |
|  7 |       4 |      21 | Bernd   |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**the query**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select CONCAT( 'SELECT column8 as \'Charges\', ', GROUP_CONCAT('SUM(IF( column9 =\'', column9,'\', column6,0)) AS \'', column9,'\'' SEPARATOR ','), ', sum(column6) as \'Total\' FROM mytable;') into @myquery from ( SELECT column9 from mytable GROUP BY column9 order by c
olumn9) as dis;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [bernd]> EXECUTE stmt;
+---------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Charges | Bernd | bob  | Eli  | Susam | Total |
+---------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
|       7 |     4 |    2 |    3 |     3 |    12 |
+---------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```